# Exam Qn: Convert do while loop to for loop (PHP)

Tags: php

Recently, my exams got over. My last exam was based on PHP. I got the following question for my exam:

"Convert the following script using for loop without affecting the output:-"

```
<?php
 //Convert into for loop
 $x = 0;
 $count = 10;
 do
 {
  echo ($count. "<BR>");
  $count = $count - 2;
  $x = $x + $count; 
 }
 while($count < 1)
 echo ($x);
?>
```

Please help me as my computer sir is out of station and I am really puzzled by it.

Comment: Your script outputs `10<br>8`. Is that right or should it decrement by 2 for 10 iterations?

Comment: please correct or pull down the question bro..

Comment: You are right. There is error in the code. But I really want to know how to change a do while loop to for loop (not for the above code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If I understand well, You have to use "for" loop, instead of "do...while", but the printed text must not change.

Try:

```
$count = 10;
$x = 0;
$firstRun = true;
for(; $count > 1 || $firstRun;) {
    $firstRun = false;
    echo ($count . "<BR>");
    $count -= 2;
    $x = $x + $count; 
}
echo ($x);
```

By the way loop is unnecessary, because $count will be greater than 1 after the first loop, so the while will get false.

EDIT

- $firstRun to avoid infiniteLoop
- $count in loop

EDIT

- Fixed code for new requirement
- Removed unnecessary code

Comment: This will result in an infinite loop. On the first iteration `10 < 1 || 10 ==  10`, on the second iteration `8 < 1 || 8 == 8`. Also, not sure what `$i < 1` is supposed to do. I think OP's PHP is wrong and that they actually want it to output 10, 8, 6, 4, 2. If that's true then, your code can simply `for($i = $count; $i < $count; $i -= 2) {...`.

Comment: Right, fixed (and now tested too xD)

Comment: Sorry, there is error in the code. But I would like to know how to change a do while loop to for loop? (not for the above code)

Comment: @Joe I just changed < to >, and removed $count from the for()

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Saphyra

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I don't know if your teacher wanted to own you... but the do{} will execute only once since $count is never < 1.

The output of your teacher's code is:
10
8

I presume there was a mistake in the code and the while would be while($count > 1) which would make more sense (since it's weird to ask for a loop to output only 10 8) and would result in this output:
10
8
6
4
2
20

Then a good for() loop would have been :

```
$x = 0;
$count = 10;
for($i = $count; $i > 1; $i -= 2)
{
    $count -= 2;
    echo $i . "<br>";
    $x += $count;
}
echo $x;
```

Which will output the same values.
If you can, ask your teacher for this, and comment the answer ^^ ahahah

Comment: Sorry, there is error in the code. But I would like to know how to change a do while loop to for loop? (not for the above code)

Comment: It doesn't work the same way, so it mainly depends on the pattern and the instructions in the do while... You can't just convert a do while to a for loop in one unique way which will work every time regardless the content of the code.

Comment: oh! ok thank you for clarifying my doubt. Now, should I remove the question as it has errors in it or should I leave it as it is?

Comment: You should edit it with the good code, then you'll get a good answer for your exam ;)